# Audio CD - Cannot mount. Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

Tags: cd

I am getting the following error when I click on the Audio CD on my launcher - "Audio CD - Cannot mount. Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)"

```
dmesg | grep CD-ROM
[    1.899068] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GU40N    A104 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.901530] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.901729] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0

$ ls -lah /dev/cd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 May  3 11:44 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
```

I cannot play the audio cd from Rhythmbox, but can only play the audio cd from VLC if I select open disc -> audio cd /dev/cdrom.

Any ideas how to get rid of the error?
[image]